# Pirkei Avos- how does a sieve retain the fine flour?

Tags: words, pirke-avot-ethicsof

Regarding the following mishna in Pirkei Avos:

> משנה אבות ה׳:ט״ו   ארבע מדות ביושבים לפני חכמים: ספוג , ומשפך, משמרת,
>   ונפה.
>
> ספוג, שהוא סופג את הכל. משפך, שמכניס בזו ומוציא בזו. משמרת, שמוציאה את
>   היין וקולטת את השמרים. ונפה, שמוציאה את הקמח וקולטת את הסלת.
>
> Pirkei Avot 5:15
>   There are four types who sit before the sages: the
>   sponge, the funnel, the strainer, and the sieve. The sponge - because
>   it absorbs everything; the funnel - because it let's in at one end and
>   out the other; the strainer - because it lets the wine out and retains
>   the sediment; the sieve - because it lets out the bran and retains the
>   fine flour.

How does a sieve retain the fine flour and let out the bran? Isn't it the other way around, that sieves have small holes and they let smaller things out, not bigger ones?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) dmr and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Wait, is the bran is bigger, what's the difference between the strainer and the sieve - they do the same job?

Comment: The question is excellent, but the answers below make it clear that the _translation_ given here is wrong. Neither solet nor kemach is translated as "bran" (generally סובין). One is high-quality flour and the others is low-quality powder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bartenura_on_Pirkei_Avot.5.15.6?lang=he) explains that the desired fine flour is actually **coarser** than the unwanted dust-like particles which are removed via the sifting process. (The bran is removed prior to this stage.)

Answer (score 4):

סלת is coarser flour; קמח is finer. Source (for example): בבלי מנחות דף עו עמוד ב.

Comment: While these are clearly correct answers, could some baker explain: How does this correspond with our flour today? It says there that if anything sticks to your hand, it's too fine. Do we have anything like that, and/or how does it work?

Comment: @MichoelR https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask … or maybe https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: I thought it should be a question, but it's just so _close_ to this question...